# Auto Height True in Accordion not working

Tags: c#, jquery, css, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a modal popup that contains accordion and each tab contains a form which is rendered using partial view.

The problem I have is that when I toggle, the accordion doesn't expand to full height (so that I can see all the form elements). Each accordion tab only extends like 20px.

How can I get it to auto extend height based on content?

```
@model Models.ContentModel.ProductContent
<div id="accordion" class="accord">
    <h2>
        <a href="#">Open New Product</a></h2>

    <div>
        @Html.Partial("../PartialViews/NewProduct", Model ?? new Models.ContentModel.ProductContent())
    </div>
    <h2>
        <a href="#">Manage Product</a></h2>
    <div>
        @Html.Partial("../PARTIALVIEWS/EDITProduct", Model ?? new Models.ContentModel.ProductContent())
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            autoHeight: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had to use 
 autoHeight: **false**
i would think it should be autoheight set to true but jquery don't work that way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            autoHeight:false
        });
    });
</script>
```